# I want to plot only some values from a data file

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot only some values from a data file
My problem is: I only want to plot the lines that are the value of some column set to some value ( run_id == 0101). Is there a gnuplot command, that makes you select the lines you want to plot?

like

```
 plot 'FTSE100.txt' using 'ATimeOnMarket' :'AAnualisedROI'
```

when, and only when, column: 'run_id' has the value '0101'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could use the ternary operator to filter the file:

```
plot 'FTSE100.txt' using (column("ATimeOnMarket")):((column("run_id) == 101)?column("AAnualisedROI"):NaN)
```

You can probably make it a little easier to read with macros:

```
set macro
ATimeOnMarket = "column('ATimeOnMarket')"
run_id = "column('run_id')
AAnualisedROI = "column('AAnualisedROI'))

plot 'FTSE100.txt' u (@ATimeOnMarket):((@run_id == 101) ? @AAnualisedROI : NaN)
```